# send news story to UIlabel objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I have a fully functioning app that i am looking to expand. I want to send "newsletter like stories" to the app so I can keep the user updated on a major program being undertaken by my organisation.

the newsletters will contain weblinks, and formatted text, so i believe i could use a UIlabel to display the information. However, the only way i currently know to update the information is to re-code the app and send it out as an update to the app (which is obviously not ideal).

What would people recommend to be able to "Publish" a newsletter within an app without having to update the app every time? I did toy with an RSS feed, but i dont believe i could write a newsletter into an RSS feed?

Comment: Erm...if u want to have new data to your app automatically, u have to have a backend that return u json or something like that, its most ideal, if your organization too lazy for it, u can just scrap their website, which should have all the news with it, then extract the data u want

Comment: I would use a UITextField instead of a UILabel

Comment: @Tj3n How would I go about creating a "backend"? what would you be recommending?

Comment: A backend mean a webservice hosted with the server (parallel with the website) that product a special url that only return data in json model (called API) for the frontend to quickly grab needed information, u can use just all the web language for creating it, u can see a very simple example in [icndb](http://www.icndb.com/api/), u call the url in the app, it return u data, so u only need to update the data that return to your device, not the app itself